# bluetooth headset is paired but not working cinammon 19.1

Tags: cinnamon

bluetooth headsets are paired but not working cinammon 19.1
although I can see the bluetooth headset  icons in Sound > Output and choose one of them, the headset is not working.
It used to be working but not anymore. I'm not sure how to fix this.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You might have to set you bluetooth headphones as the default sink (output device) in PulseAudio. I'm not 100% sure how do so graphically, but I only know how to do it from the command line.

Here's how to do it:

```
pacmd set-default-sink "$(pacmd list-sinks | grep 'name: <blue' | sed -e 's/.*<//g' -e 's/>//g' | head -1)"
```

In theory, if you go into the application menu, click "sound", and select your bluetooth device from there (in the "Device" section), that should also make it the default. You may need to restart whatever program you are using for music/sound, but I could be wrong.